# Resize UITableView to fit all cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView within an auto-sized UITableViewCell to display a variable, but small number of items. I want the nested UITableView to expand to display all of its rows.  (I know this may not be the best way to do things, so please bear with me on the premise.)

The problem I'm having is that the UITableView does not have an intrinsic size based on the size of all of its cells.  Is there any way to force all of the cells to load an then compute an intrinsic size?  (Or some other way to have a full-sized nested UITableView.)

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, not the best way to do things. `UITableView` is a good thing to use when you have a large list and you need to recycle `UITableViewCell`s to keep your memory footprint low. If you have a small number of items inside a `UITableViewCell` why not just display them as sub-`UIView`s of your `UITableViewCell` - you gain no advantage by using a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I guess I was just being lazy... The one problem I do have is that each list is dynamic and consists of different cell types, so it seems easier to use a table view than to manually construct the views each time.  One of the cell types includes a variable sized list as well.  I'll begin with constructing that list-cell since I have a lot of legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where you define the height of each cell. I believe the default is 44. You can just take those values and then multiply them by the number of cells you're populating and that will be the height your UITableView should be.

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm using iOS 8's automatic layout functionality.  It looks for an intrinsic size of the cells (so far so good) but because I have a table view within a table view cell, it seems like the nested one does not have an intrinsic size at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that it was a tableview within a cell. That was my fault.